# How to add duplicate values to graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, duplicates

I have a dataset where there are duplicate values in the y column. When I plot them using ggplot the duplicates are merged together, but I need them to be graphed separately so that all data points are shown on the graph. I'm not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=feeding_type,y=dung_count,color=habitat))+   
  geom_point()
```

Edit: After adding geom_point(position="jitter") I got this graph:

[image: graph 2]

Is there any way to stack the dots so that it is more obvious which points go with each variable?

Comment: Try making `geom_point()` into `geom_point(position = "jitter")`

Comment: You could try `geom_point(alpha = 0.2)` or some other alpha value.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: as @benjamin pointed out, using the ```alpha``` argument will make the points transparant, changing the color when they overlap. Also consider using ```theme_dark()```, it will make colors pop out which in turn will enhance the color difference a bit.